# How to execute some action after the JFrame are displayed

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe

I have this GUI application, and I want to execute a custom action inmediatelly when the user open the application, but after the GUI are shown.

So, I put the call to the action into the `public Main()` of the JFrame like this:

```
public Main() {
    initComponents();
    ExecuteAfter();
}
```

Where `ExecuteAfter()` is the method that contain the acction, or actions to execute.

This works fine, but not in the way I want. This way, the action executes allways before the `JFrame` are displayed, that is before the aplication windows appear in the screen. What I want is that execute the action only after the `JFrame` are displayed, that is after the aplication windows appear in the screen.

I tried put the call into the `public static void main(String args[])` because there's where the `JFrame` is created and displayed. But doesn't work because the method isn't static, and I can't put static that method because it use some components of the `JFrame` that are already initialized non-static by the IDE.

So, the question is: Where I need to put the call for the action can be executed after the `JFrame` are displayed on the screen? Or there's other way of doing that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered trying to use a `WindowListener`? Have a look at [How to Write Window Listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) for more details.  Alternatively you could wrap the call in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` call. I'd probably be tempted to do both

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks! That solved the problem. I used a `WindowListener` and works perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a `WindowListener` and solved the problem.

Instead of put the call in the constructor `public Main()` or in the main `public static void main(String args[])` which cannot be done, I configured a `WindowsListener` for do the call. Like that:

```
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
    ExecuteAfter();
}
```

And works perfectly in the way I want.

Thanks @MadProgrammer for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you question, I use a similar case for my project. I was needed to start timer when JFrame show, so this is how i do that.

So i use 2 methods and 1 constructor. First method (exp. Name: prepare GUI), here you can add all thinks what you need to create JFrame, JPanel....and that method I call in constructor. In second method (exp. Name: start GUI) you will add all components to JPanel/s, JPanel/s to JFrame, and set JFrame visible = (true) and then add your method ExecuteAfter(). That second method(prepare GUI) you need to call in main method. I hope that's will help you.

Comment: The IDE where I'm working make automatically one constructor, that I refer in the question `public Main()`, where "Main" is the name of the `JFrame` that can be any name; and the `main`, properly, `public static void main(String args[])` that call the constructor and display the windows. The problem is that I can't put any call on the `main` because it is `static` and the call wouldn't be for the reasons I explain in the question.

Comment: I already solved the problem with the `WindowListener` @MadProgrammer answer. Thanks!